# keep only one li node open in tree view display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to hide other siblings li when i click one li to diplay tree view.
Only one node should open and its children elements have to expand. check the fiddle links below .
    Html code :

Part 1

- Item A

  - Sub-item 1
  - Sub-item 2
  - Sub-item 3
- Item B

  - Sub-item 1
  - Sub-item 2
  - Sub-item 3
- Item C

  - Sub-item 1
  - Sub-item 2
  - Sub-item 3
- Item D

  - Sub-item 1
  - Sub-item 2
  - Sub-item 3
- Item E

  - Sub-item 1
  - Sub-item 2
  - Sub-item 3

```
  <li><a href="#">Part 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">Part 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

css :
ul.tree li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

ul.tree li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul.tree li.open > ul {
    display: block;
}

ul.tree li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.tree li a:before {
    height: 1em;
    padding:0 .1em;
    font-size: .8em;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.3em;
    top: .2em;
}

ul.tree li > a:not(:last-child):before {
    content: '+';
}

ul.tree li.open > a:not(:last-child):before {
    content: '-';
}

js code :

var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tree a:not(:last-child)');
for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++){
    tree[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var parent = e.target.parentElement;
        var classList = parent.classList;
        if(classList.contains("open")) {
            classList.remove('open');
            var opensubs = parent.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');
            for(var i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++){
                opensubs[i].classList.remove('open');
            }
        } else {
            classList.add('open'); // Here only i want that condition to check li is already opened or not//
        }
    });
}

For more info : https://jsfiddle.net/te366hu2/2/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified you js code a bit to collapse the sibling nodes. Full working fiddle [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/nvf0g4wn/)

```
var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tree a:not(:last-child)');
for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++){
    tree[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var parent = e.target.parentElement;
        var classList = parent.classList;
        var closeAllOpenSiblings = function(){        
            var opensubs = parent.parentElement.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');
            for(var i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++){
                opensubs[i].classList.remove('open');
            }
        }
        if(classList.contains("open")) {
            classList.remove('open');
        } else {
            closeAllOpenSiblings();
            classList.add('open');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work!
All info in comments:
https://jsfiddle.net/xog7hxLs/

```
var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tree a:not(:last-child)');
for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++){
    tree[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var element = e.target.parentElement; //actually this is just the elem itself
        var parent = element.parentElement //real parent
        var opensubs = parent.querySelectorAll(':scope .open'); //check which are opened on parent
        if(opensubs.length !=0) {
                  for(var i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++){
                opensubs[i].classList.remove('open'); //closing opened previously
            }
        } 
            element.classList.add('open'); //opening current

    });
}
```

Comment: This is also an answer buddies :-) not able to select as answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the node open event to look through the tree and close other nodes.

```
$('#tree').on('open_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    var nodesToKeepOpen = [];

        // get all parent nodes to keep open
        $('#'+data.node.id).parents('.jstree-node').each(function() {
           nodesToKeepOpen.push(this.id);
        });

        // add current node to keep open
        nodesToKeepOpen.push( data.node.id );

        // close all other nodes
        $('.jstree-node').each( function() {
            if( nodesToKeepOpen.indexOf(this.id) === -1 ) {
                $("#tree").jstree().close_node(this.id);
            }
        })
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/dxm6w9ur/)